# Mandrill tracking domain causing SSL issue

Tags: ssl, mandrill

We use Mandrill for our transactional emails and have a custom Tracking Domain setup, following Mandrill instructions:

> To enable tracking on a subdomain, you must set up a CNAME record in DNS pointing your subdomain to mandrillapp.com

We use AWS Route 52 and so have the following CNAME record setup:

| Type | Domain Name | Canonical Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | clicks.example.com | mandrillapp.com |

However, when you users click on our links they get a warning in Chrome saying **Your connection is not private**.

Looking at this tracking domain on [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.htm) it's says:

> None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (clicks.example.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser.
> Common name: mandrillapp.com
> SANs: mandrillapp.com, [www.mandrillapp.com](http://www.mandrillapp.com), *.in1.mandrillapp.com, *.in2.mandrillapp.com, *.mandrillapp.com
> Organization: The Rocket Science Group LLC

Has anyone else faced this issue with using customer Tracking Domains and SSL on Mandrill?

Comment: Are you sure that SSL certificate matches the custom domain? and CNAME record points `correctly` to Mandrill's domain?